Can I analyse the separate items of my multi-item scale?
Can I analyse my likert scale items individually? What i mean is: I have a question with 5 statements (all on 5-point likert scale): "I feel sad", "I feel concerned", "I feel worried", I feel soft-hearted" and "I feel bad". I use the same scale across my 2 IV levels. Can I take an individual statement, "I feel sad" and perform a t-test for the responses received for the 2 conditions to say across which condition participants feel more sadness?

This is a very interesting problem, and there is a contest between wanting to get an overall answer of which treatment is better vs. getting separate answers for each domain.  At any rate, the scales are ordinal and need to be treated as such to avoid any equal spacing assumption within an item.  To get a total scale, as @BenP said it is sometimes OK to add them up to create a semi-continuous variable (which still should be analyzed as ordinal perhaps).  It may be better to analyze the multiple items in a multivariate way.  For example one can create a tall and thin dataset (one row per subject per item) and use a random effects proportional odds ordinal regression model to handle within-subject correlation across the items.  An initial model could have a single condition effect, and testing this single effect will assess for overall benefit of one of the conditions.
In R these models can be fitted using the ordinal package (frequentist) or the brms or rmsb packages (Bayesian, which handles random effects more elegantly than frequentist methods).
GEE with a cluster sandwich variance correction may also be used.  GEE is a large sample method that is not robust to missing data that are not missing completely at random.  If you don’t have much missing data this won’t be much of an issue.

Sure you can analyse each item separately, but I would consider another test then. The sadness item has values 1 to 5, probably going from "not sad at all" to "very sad". The four intervals between adjacent values do not represent the same "psychological distance" in sadness. It could be so that the difference between "very sad" and "sad" is experienced as smaller by your respondents than the distance between "neutral" and "sad", and this could even be different for different people. However, the difference in the scale values is 1 in both situations. To be short: it is hard to defend that the values 1 to 5 you assign, can be considered as points on an interval scale, like e.g. "temperature". The values are typically ordinal, a higher value representing more sadness but not in the same amount for each 1 unit increase! And therefore it is better to use a test that also considers order, instead of one that uses group means, which are in turn based on equal distances. An appropriate test would be the Mann-Whitney test.
Notice that if you use the sum of all five items, this sum would range from 5 to 25. Each small increase of 1 unit of the sum score is then often considered to represent the same increase of "depression", no matter if the sum score increase from 6 to 7, or from 16 to 17. This is still arguable, but often done that way. And hence, the t-test comes into the picture then.
For the record I would like to add the above answer is not about whether analysing separate items is recommendable in general, when you have a number of items to measure some underlying construct, like "depression". If the items all measure the same construct, using them "together" in some way, enables you to measure the construct more reliably than using only one item. But that is another discussion.
